# ServiceStack Hot Reloading Typescript

Tags: servicestack

I'm using .net core and ServiceStack Angular SPA project template, and I want to enable hot reloading.

From what I saw on site [here](http://templates.servicestack.net/docs/hot-reloading) I only need to add:

`Plugins.Add(new TemplatePagesFeature());`

`<i hidden>{{ '/js/hot-loader.js' | ifDebugIncludeScript }}</i>`

And:

`SetConfig(new HostConfig
      {
        DebugMode = true
      });`

And this works for HTML files, however, nothing happens when I modify TS files (in console or browser), do I need to configure something else in order to allow that?

**EDIT**

I thought that this will also start something like `npm run dev` (to run `--aot`) but does not look like that, so my temporary solution until I find more elegant way is to use something like this and [shell extension](https://github.com/robisim74/AngularCliAspNetCore/blob/master/Extensions/ShellExtensions.cs):

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   app.Shell("npm run dev");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Development workflow for each template can be found on the project page for each template. E.g. the [Angular SPA Project Template](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/angular-spa#development-workflow) requires that you run either `npm run dev` or `npm run serve` which starts a watched client build:

### Development workflow

Our recommendation during development is to run the `dev` npm script or Gulp task and leave it running in the background:

```
$ npm run dev
```

This initially generates a full development build of your Web App then stays running in the background to process files as they’re changed. This enables the normal dev workflow of running your ASP.NET Web App, saving changes locally which are then reloaded using ServiceStack’s built-in hot reloading. Alternatively hitting `F5` will refresh the page and view the latest changes.

Each change updates the output dev resources so even if you stop the dev task your Web App remains in a working state that’s viewable when running the ASP.NET Web App.

#### Live reload with built-in Dev Server

The alternative dev workflow is to run the `serve` npm or gulp script to run Create React App's built-in Webpack dev server:

```
$ npm run serve
```

This launches the Webpack dev server listening at `http://localhost:4200/` and configured to proxy all non-Webpack HTTP requests to the ASP.NET Web App where it handles all Server API requests. The benefit of viewing your App through the Webpack dev server is its built-in Live Reload feature where it will automatically reload the page as resources are updated.

#### Watched .NET Core builds

.NET Core projects can also benefit from Live Coding using dotnet watch which performs a “watched build” where it automatically stops, recompiles and restarts your .NET Core App when it detects source file changes. You can start a watched build from the command-line with:

```
$ dotnet watch run
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, detailed as always. Is there any big disadvantage of executing these commands directly from `program.cs` or `startup.cs` so we can just hit F5 from VS and get everything up and running at once?

Comment: @ShP Most fxs the client builds are run independently from the command line, Startup time would be worse if you had to restart client builds for every server change.

Comment: Yeah, make sense. Tnx again.